# Django: How to autocomplete user-creator field of a model in admin-panel

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model, admin

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_media_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    group = models.ForeignKey('bot_users.BotUserGroup', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I log in in admin-panel (as a superuser, as a staff. Doesn't matter) and I want user field to be autocompleted with user who made this POST model instance in admin-panel. How can I do that?

I've tried save() method, but it doesn't work for me. Also save_model method in admin.py

P.S. Function of making posts in the project can only be made from admin-panel

Comment: I got it, blank have to be True